# Edge node and local File system relation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there any connection between edge node and Local file system in Hadoop? I have studied that edge node is a gate way to enter hdfs. But while transferring files between hdfs and local file system using put or get commands, why there is no edge node?

Answer (score 3):

Edge node in your hadoop cluster acts as client machine/node which can help your applications to submit jobs to hadoop cluster, it's like an entry point. When you use put or get command to load or upload the files between HDFS and your local filesystem it does not necessarily mean edge node, your local file system can be any node in your cluster where you have the file you want to put in HDFS or get from HDFS.

Comment: sorry could you please elaborate? what does "it doesn't necessarily mean edge node" in your sentence mean? r u saying there is no edge node intervention while using put or get commands and transferring files to or from hdfs?

Comment: When you run put or get command for moving files between local file system and HDFS, the local file system can be of the node/machine from where you can hdfs command. So, if you run your get and put from edge node it will access local system of edge node. If you run get and put command from any other node, say master node or data node it will be accessing the local file system of that node.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me sonwane. But my question is, If we run put command to insert into hdfs from some other node, does it need to enter edge node as it is gateway of hdfs? @snehalSonwane

Comment: Nope, unless you have assigned data node on edge node. If you run cli commands from other nodes than edge node it will not interact with your edge node.

Comment: @RamtejaGuthikonda Edge nodes are not "HDFS gateways". They are "client bridges". If fact, edge nodes don't even require local persistent disk storage.